# Dynamics AX Document Services salesSalesOrder error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I have a quastion regarding document services

I just want to create salesorders through document services I just follow the straight forward procces of  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh352313.aspx.

I made the modifications that coresponds to my system through the help of the exception log of administration panel . Now I have to face the fact that my xml file is deleted and I have no salesOrders in salestable and not a response xml into response file.

Then my next action was to debug the service...attach the proccess load the debug symbols etc....

The time that I triger the services did not hit the breakpoint in the class/method SalesSalesOrder.read but instand I get a funny error from VisualStudio which make me to feel blind , also note that does not exist any error in exception log of dynamics ax or in the  batch job.

The error from VS.
"An exception of type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ErrorException' occurred in Dynamics.Ax.Application.dll854.netmodule but was not handled in user code"

Can anyone help me  or face something similar at the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

iN inbound port I should specify the company id, 
then everything works fine. The reason was that the default company was empty and the new salesorders cannot passed validation.